# How to Insert # of Rows based on Value Criteria in Column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, insert

I've spent hours trying to find the right code. I already have a 'Sub going, and this is the next step in the Sub.

I have a data set where I want to insert 3 rows if Column("C:C") < 1

Further up the module, I have:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workseets("Report1")

I didn't know if I needed to set another DIM..
This is what I have so far:

'Insert 3 Blank Rows after $ Share < 1.0

```
With ws
    If Range("C:C").Value < "1.0" Then
    Rows.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
End With
```

But I'm getting the Run-Time error '13':
Type Mismatch

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to loop through the cells in column C...

Comment: ...and since you're inserting rows, working from the bottom up will be easier.

Comment: And without dots the `With` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

When adding or deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom of the sheet to the top:

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 2 Step -1
    With ws.Cells(i, 3)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 And .Value < 1 Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

EDIT: for your revised description

```
For i = 2 To lr
    With ws.Cells(i, 3)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 And .Value < 1 Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next i

Dim i As Long, n As Long, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
```

EDIT2: add rows above the <1 values

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set c = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)
Do While c.Row > 1
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And c.Value < 1 Then
        'insert 3 rows above
        For n = 1 To 3
            c.EntireRow.Insert
            Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0) '<<adjust for added row
        Next n
        Exit Do '<< stop checking
    End If
    Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Tim, is it just a best practice to use the `0` in `Offset` and the `1` in the `Resize`?

Comment: I can't say what's best practice - I like to be explicit even when it's not "required"...  That way you don't have to remember all the rules for what's required.

Comment: I missed some information... The problem with this code is it's adding 3 rows to the bottom.  I have the rows Filtered Largest to Smallest, and I only need 3 rows at the first <1 from the top.  For Example:  38.4, 10.4, 3.5, 1.0, "","","",0.09,0.03

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you!  I'm wanting to understand the "i", If I don't want this to loop, and only add 3 rows to the first occurrence please?